# How to sync data from SQL Server to Oracle using Grails

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, grails

I'm using Grails 3.2.8, Java 8 & Oracle 11g.
I need to insert and sync data from SQL Server to Oracle for 1 table by using Grails.
I have tried with Oracle GoldenGate but I'm unable to implement that.
Is there any other way to do so? If grails multi-datasource can give solution then how to do that?

Comment: Is this a one shot operation? How many rows? Are the data types of the rows anything other than numbers and text e.g. blob, clob?

Comment: No. Its a continuous operation. There are 6 column in my oracle table which contains numeric, text and date value.

Answer (score 0):

You could create connections to the 2 databases using groovy Sql & not bother with Grails domain classses, maybe in a [quartz job](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/quartz) like below which runs every hour.

Quartz job

```
class dbMoveJob {
    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'dbMoveJobCron', cronExpression: "0 0 0/1 * * ?"
    }

    def dbMoveService

    def execute() {
        dbMoveService.dbMove()
    }
}
```

Service

```
import groovy.sql.*
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value

class dbMoveService {
    static final String SQL_SERVER_DRIVER = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
    static final String ORACLE_DRIVER = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

    @Value( '${sqlServerUrl}' )
    def sqlServerUrl
    @Value( '${sqlServerUser}' )
    def sqlServerUser
    @Value( '${sqlServerPw}' )
    def sqlServerPw

    @Value( '${oracleUrl}' )
    def oracleUrl
    @Value( '${oracleUser}' )
    def oracleUser
    @Value( '${oraclePw}' )
    def oraclePw

    def dbMove() {
        def sqlServerDb
        def oracleDb

        try {
            sqlServerDb = Sql.newInstance( sqlServerUrl, sqlServerUser, sqlServerPw, SQL_SERVER_DRIVER ) 
            oracleDb = Sql.newInstance( oracleUrl, oracleUser, oraclePw, ORACLE_DRIVER ) 

            sqlServerDb.eachRow( 'select * from sql_server_table' ) {
                oracleDb.executeInsert( 'insert into oracle_table( oraclefield1, oraclefield2 ) values( ?, ? )', [it.sqlserverfield1, it.sqlserverfield2] )
            }
        }
        finally {
            sqlServerDb?.close()
            oracleDb?.close()
        }
    }
}
```

@Value annotated variables will be derived from application.yml.